# processes hanging when trying to access a file

Tags: filesystems, ext4

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.5 and the ext4 filesystem, and I have a file which causes processes to hang when they read it.

For example:

```
$ cat /path/to/file.txt
```

and then from a separate terminal:

```
$ sudo cat /proc/24147/stack
[<ffffffff811937dd>] wait_on_page_bit_killable+0xcd/0xf0
[<ffffffff81193c86>] generic_file_read_iter+0x486/0x6b0
[<ffffffff8121395e>] new_sync_read+0x9e/0xe0
[<ffffffff812139c9>] __vfs_read+0x29/0x40
[<ffffffff81213f96>] vfs_read+0x86/0x130
[<ffffffff81214ce5>] SyS_read+0x55/0xc0
[<ffffffff81829d4e>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x22/0xc1
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

I have many processes hung reading this file. Here's another example with a different call stack:

```
$ less /path/to/file.txt
```

and then from a separate terminal:

```
$ sudo cat /proc/23006/stack
[<ffffffff8140f954>] call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x14/0x30
[<ffffffff812a1e83>] ext4_map_blocks+0x443/0x5a0
[<ffffffff812edb98>] ext4_mpage_readpages+0x368/0x920
[<ffffffff8129f626>] ext4_readpages+0x36/0x40
[<ffffffff811a0b89>] __do_page_cache_readahead+0x199/0x240
[<ffffffff811a0d6d>] ondemand_readahead+0x13d/0x250
[<ffffffff811a101e>] page_cache_sync_readahead+0x2e/0x50
[<ffffffff81193d4a>] generic_file_read_iter+0x54a/0x6b0
[<ffffffff8121395e>] new_sync_read+0x9e/0xe0
[<ffffffff812139c9>] __vfs_read+0x29/0x40
[<ffffffff81213f96>] vfs_read+0x86/0x130
[<ffffffff81214ce5>] SyS_read+0x55/0xc0
[<ffffffff81829d4e>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x22/0xc1
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

I need to narrow down the actual problem a bit. The context is somewhat involved (I'm running Apache and using mod_wsgi, and then Python code is writing to the file which is a log file, this volume is a RAID array on top of the instance store on an AWS instance etc, etc).

Is it possible to get a linux box into a state where `cat`'ing a file causes the terminal to hang as I'm showing above. From there I may determine what additional context (if any) would be useful here.

I should mention that this happens on a certain production machine (which sees heavy use) every month or so. I can restart the machine to recover, but I'm interested in understanding this state which it's in. Ideally I'd like to prevent this from happening in the first place.

Comment: I believe this is the same: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350761/reading-text-file-hangs-with-wait-on-page-bit-killable

Comment: @V13 I added another example from the same machine with a different call stack. I'm not sure it's the same problem as the other question you referenced, but I guess that's the thing - I have no idea what it could be and was hoping for some input to narrow it down a bit.

Comment: Can you SIGKILL that process? if not, then they're the same question, your filesystem or disk is broken, try to do offline fsck.

Comment: I can kill the `cat` process but not the `less` one

Comment: Did you try fsck? It looks like a corrupted ext4 filesystem that triggers a "buggy" codepath that's not normally exercised

Comment: That's really what I'm asking - can the filesystem get into a state where reads hang the calling process? I'm wondering if anyone has insight into whether this is a bug somewhere, and if so where that bug might be. I'd like to prevent this from happening again, not just fix it.

Comment: I'd guess that the second stack trace is from here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/94bd8a05cd4de344a9a57e52ef7d99550251984f/fs/ext4/inode.c#L557 (depends on your exact kernel version). Opening a bug wouldn't be a bad idea. You should also probably do an fsck -N (no changes) on the filesystems to see what kind of errors it has.